# nginx sites available redirecting badly

Tags: nginx, server, multiple-sites

I have a server with multiple sites running on nginx. I'm trying to add another one, and somehow I keep getting redirected to the wrong path.

What I usually do is copy from a working one and change the domain and paths, then create de symlink. I've also checked that they both have the same permissions, so I'm not seeing any mistake on my part. all paths work and of course I've restarted nginx. I also restarted the whole server out of desperation.

The failing one

```
server {
listen   80;

root /data/alvarezarango.com/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name alvarezarango.com www.alvarezarango.com;

error_log /data/alvarezarango.com/logs/error.log error;
access_log /data/alvarezarango.com/logs/access.log;



location ~ [^/].php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}


}
```

the working one:

```
server {
listen   80;

root /data/spiraxtime.com/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name spiraxtime.com www.spiraxtime.com;

error_log /data/spiraxtime.com/logs/error.log error;
access_log /data/spiraxtime.com/logs/access.log;



location ~ [^/].php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}


}
```

I get redirected to my main domain, but i can't see why. Is anything I can check to understand the redirects?

Comment: Use `nginx -T` to confirm that it is reading the entire configuration.

Comment: @RichardSmith nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful this is the only feedback it threw. is there a way to test vhosts files? or get a log about them excuting?